# How do I create a Datalab instance with a GPU?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I tried running:

`datalab beta create-gpu datalab-gpu-instance-name`

but it gives me this error:

`usage: datalab [-h] [--project PROJECT] [--zone ZONE] [--quiet]
               [--verbosity {debug,info,warning,error,critical,none}]
               {stop,create,list,connect,delete} ...
datalab: error: argument subcommand: invalid choice: 'beta' (choose from 'stop', 'create', 'list', 'connect', 'delete')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your version of the datalab command line tool.

Run: `gcloud components update`